# how to profile(timing) in powershell

Tags: powershell, profiling

My powershell script runs slowly, is there any way to profile the powershell script?

Comment: Will you share the code? The most probable reason is dependency on external resources (net, file system, ..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do [random-pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) in the Powershell debugger. Get the script running, and while it's running, type Ctrl-C. It will halt and then you can display the stack. That will tell you where it is, what it's doing, and why. Do this several times, not just once.

Suppose it is taking twice as long as it could. That means each time you interrupt it the probability you will catch it doing the slow thing is 50%. So if you interrupt it 10 times, you should see that on about 5 samples.

Suppose it is taking 5 times as long as it could. That means 4/5 of the time is being wasted, so you should see it about 8 times out of 10.

Even if as little as 1/5 of the time is being wasted, you should see it about 2 times out of 10. Anything you see on as few as 2 samples, if you can find a faster way to do it, will give you a good speed improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Posting your script here would really help in giving an accurate answer.

You can use Measure-Command to see how much time each statement in your script is taking. However, you have to wrap each statement in Measure-Command.

Trace-Command can also be used to trace what is happening when the script runs. The output from this cmdlet can be quite verbose.

http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2010/06/powershell-2-0-one-cmdlet-at-a-time-104-trace-command.html

Comment: You can use `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1 # or 2`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recent blog about speeding up for loops that shows you how to build a "test harness" for timing loops:

http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/16/make-your-powershell-for-loops-4x-faster/

Comment: Link is broken but the code's still available here.
https://github.com/dfinke/powershellScripts/blob/master/Make%20PowerShell%20For%20Loops%20Faster/Do-Tests.ps1

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple poor-man's profiler is simply to step through the code in the ISE debugger. You can sometimes feel how slow a part of the code is just by stepping over it or by running to some breakpoint.